# Print every other string character * Index position* 2+2

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to build a Python function that returns a string that contains every other character duplicated by the following algorithm:

```
Index position * 2 + 2
```

for example: `Testing --> TTssssssiiiiiiiiiigggggggggggggg`

Below is my code but I get an error:

> IndexError: string index out of range

Version A:

```
def string_expansion(input_string):
i = 0
while i < len(string):
    i += 1
    if input_string[::2] == string[i]:
        return input_string[i] * (i * 2) + 2
```

second version returns none when I pass an argument

Version B:

```
def string_expansion(input_string):
i = 0
while i < len(string):
    if input_string[::2] == string[i]:
        return input_string[i] * (i * 2) + 2
    i += 1
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: how are you defining the "string" variable?   Also if you're using step size of 2 on one string, while just a incrementing by 1 on the input_string, that could be the reason you're getting an index error.

Comment: You are incrementing `i` too soon in the first version; `i = len(string) - 1` is the last valid string index, so `i + 1` is invalid.

Comment: You're also returning too soon; you need to build up the return value during each iteration, *then* return the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your Question Correctly, you need to build and store string value during each iteration:

```
def string_expansion(input_string):
    i = 0
    str=""
    while i < len(input_string):
        str =str+input_string[i] * ((i * 2) + 2)
        i=i+2        
    print(str)
string_expansion("testing")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this...

```
def string_expansion(input_string):
    return ''.join([e[1]*(e[0]*2+2) for e in enumerate(input_string) if e[0]%2 == 0])

string_expansion('Testing')
'TTssssssiiiiiiiiiigggggggggggggg'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def iter_tokens(inp):
    for ind, ch in enumerate(inp):
    if ind % 2 == 0:
        yield ch * (ind * 2 + 2)

# Call this one
def str_exp(inp):
    return ''.join(iter_tokens(inp))
```